# Images disappear when nested inside a table and appended to a new document. Bug or did I miss something?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to append a Google Docs document to another one using Apps Script. Everything works fine except whenever there is an image nested inside a table cell, the image will disappear (just a placeholder with an exclamation mark is displayed).

[image]

Piece of code (just for tables):

```
function mergeTestMinimal() {
  var body = DocumentApp.openById("1XmWwK2ni2JyX4Ii1ow19AehLqPkdYGOsj5XFSrlkaw4").getBody(); //Document to insert new content
  var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById("1ygNn1kgiFchuSf1mBs6RiS4GiBx3KPcKK07E_WWlsBE").getBody(); //To be copied
  var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();
  for (var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j) {  
    var element = otherBody.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE){
      body.appendTable(element);
    } 
  }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code or is it a bug in the append method?

**EDIT:** I read the suggested links but they don't solve the issue. It is explained how to merge two documents in the same way as I did it, but nested table images get corrupted there, too.
`otherBody.getChild(j)` seems to lose the nested table images. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Hi, I cannot find the documentation related to `getActiveSection()`, can you provide a link to it?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for looking into the issue. Yes, you are right, the method seems to be obsolete (but is still working). I replaced it with `getBody()`. It does not affect the issue.

Comment: Can you provide sample documents to test this behavior?

Comment: When this document is merged with another one (e.g. a blank one) the images get corrupted: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HqrAZmTmisTi-902ovhOOBkrAZ3JXVG400xvVI4Hxso/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Here my maybe not very elegant workaround. The problem was that `body.getChild(index)` lost nested images inside a table cell.
This also happened when I inserted or appended a table as a whole, no matter if the source was a body child or from `body.getTables()`. The images got corrupted.

I now run manually through the table cell by cell in the aftermath and replace each corrupted inline imgage (placeholders with exclamation mark) with the belonging image from `body.getTables()`. Now they are displayed correctly. Very strange.

Be careful: If a table is nested inside a table, it will be an additional entry in the array `body.getTables()` but NOT be part of the body children `body.getChild(index)`(--> only top level tables). I had to link the two in a way that the indices don't get mixed up.

**Here my code:**

```
function mergeDocs() {
  var dstBody = DocumentApp.openById("1XmWwK2ni2JyX4Ii1ow19AehLqPkdYGOsj5XFSrlkaw4").getBody(); //Doc to append content to
  var srcBody = DocumentApp.openById("1ygNn1kgiFchuSf1mBs6RiS4GiBx3KPcKK07E_WWlsBE").getBody(); //Source Doc to be copied
  var totalElements = srcBody.getNumChildren();
  
  for (var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j) {
    var dstChild = srcBody.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = dstChild.getType();
    
    if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) dstBody.appendParagraph(dstChild);
    else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE){
      var allSrcTables = srcBody.getTables();
      var tableIndex;
      var tables = allSrcTables.forEach(function(table){
        // !! getChildIndex(table) will crash if a table is nested inside is a table --> nested tables are part of body.getTables() but NOT part of the body children (body.getChild(j)): No belonging body child index can be found for a subtable!!
        //only execude the method getChildIndex() if a table is not nested inside another table
        if(table.getParent().getType() !== DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_CELL){
          var childIndex = srcBody.getChildIndex(table); 
          if (childIndex == j){
            tableIndex = allSrcTables.indexOf(table);
          }
        }
      });
      var srcTable = allSrcTables[tableIndex];
      var newTable = dstBody.insertTable( dstBody.getNumChildren()-1, srcTable.copy());
      //replace all corrupted inline images with working ones from srcBody.getTables();
      replaceCorruptedImages(srcTable, newTable);
    }
    else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) dstBody.appendListItem(dstChild);
    else throw new Error('Unknown element type: ' + type);
  }
}

function replaceCorruptedImages(srcTable, dstTable) {
  var numRows = dstTable.getNumRows();
  var dstRow, numCells, dstCell, actCellIndex;
  
  for (var actRowIndex = 0; actRowIndex < numRows; actRowIndex++) {
    dstRow = dstTable.getRow(actRowIndex);
    numCells = dstRow.getNumCells();
    
    for (actCellIndex = 0; actCellIndex < numCells; actCellIndex++) {
      dstCell = dstRow.getCell(actCellIndex);
      //dstCell.clear();
      var srcCell = srcTable.getCell(actRowIndex, actCellIndex);
      var numCellChildren = srcCell.getNumChildren();
      
      for (var y = 0; y < numCellChildren; y++) {
        var cellChild = srcCell.getChild(y);
        var childCopy = cellChild.copy();
        
        switch(childCopy.getType()) {
          case DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE:
            dstCell.getChild(y).removeFromParent();
            dstCell.appendInlineImage(childCopy);
          
          //images may be nested inside a paragraph
          case DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH: 
            var numParaChildren = childCopy.getNumChildren();
            for (var z = 0; z < numParaChildren; z++){
              var paraChild = childCopy.getChild(z);
              var paraChildCopy = paraChild.copy();
              if (paraChildCopy.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE){
                dstCell.getChild(y).getChild(z).removeFromParent();
                dstCell.getChild(y).appendInlineImage(paraChildCopy);
              }
            }
            break;
          
          // recursive function in case a table is nested inside a table
          case DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE:
            replaceCorruptedImages(cellChild, dstCell.getChild(y));
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's to share a solution. I deleted the first paragraph.